# How to to convert a .vhdx file inside an azure blob to a .vhd file so i can create a VM from it

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, azure-devops, cloud, virtual-machine

I have a google cloud storage that stores disk images as .vhdx, i am using azure factory to send these disk images over to an Azure blob storage.
the process of sending the .vhdx files completes with no problem, the problem now is i want to convert these .vhdx files in my azure blob to a .vhd format so that i can use them to create Vms, how can this conversion be done?

Comment: Not sure how to convert vhdx files (if even possible) but GCP has a migration tool from Azure to GCP https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.5/how-to/migrate-azure-to-gcp/migrating-azure-vms

Comment: Have you checked that you need to convert VHDX to VHD? The term **VHD** includes both the original layout (VHD) and the newer layout (VHDX).

Comment: yes i have checked and tried to create the VM from a vhdx and it gives me an error that the extension must be .vhd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to download the .vhdx file to your local.

Then you can use the below PowerShell command to convert the .vhdx file to .vhd file:

```
Convert-VHD –Path c:\CreateVM\ucs.vhdx –DestinationPath c:\CreateVM\ucs.vhd -VHDType Fixed
```

Now, you can upload the .vhd file to the Azure Blob Storage

Then you can use the .vhd file to create VMs